# single line appears as vertical-center aligned

Tags: iphone, uilabel, xcode4.5

I have a long text string that I feed into a `UILabel` for display. The `UILabel` is dynamically set up to provide sufficient space for the text

```
        specialities1 =[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [specialities1 setFrame:CGRectMake(124,218,size8.width, size8.height)];
        specialities1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];**strong text**
        specialities1.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeClip;
        specialities1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
        specialities1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",temp ];
        specialities1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
        [specialities1 setNumberOfLines:0];
        [specialities1 sizeToFit];
        [testscroll addSubview:specialities1];
```

My problem is if text contains only single line then it appears as vertical-center aligned. That alignment is not matching with my respective label in front of it.

Comment: If you work in ios6 then use `NSTextAlignmentRight` rather than `UITextAlignmentRight`.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
specialities1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
specialities1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

Comment: am not getting proper alignment although i use them

Comment: you are also use UILineBreakModeWordWrap mode when you get height of text

Answer (score 0):

```
specialities1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; // UITextAlignmentCenter
```

Choose what you need, depending on the situation you encounter.

Comment: am not getting proper format although i use all the alignments (right,left,center) no change in the output